# grunt-contrib-requirejs doesn't resolve my runtime module injection

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I have one problem. In my project i'm using runtime module injection. When i use **require.js** framework all works ok. But when i try to make solid js file with **grunt-contrib-requirejs** it doesn't find my injecting module.

piece of my code whre i'm injecting module

```
_.each(collection.models, function (model) {
    require(['application/views/' + model.get("className")], function (view) {
       view();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/optimization.html

> The optimizer will only combine modules that are specified in arrays
>   of string literals that are passed to top-level require and define
>   calls, or the require('name') string literal calls in a simplified
>   CommonJS wrapping. So, it will not find modules that are loaded via a
>   variable name:
>
> ```
> var mods = someCondition ? ['a', 'b'] : ['c', 'd'];
> require(mods);`
> ```

To include dynamically loaded files, use the `include` option in your task configuration:

```
include: ['a.js', 'b.js', 'c.js']
```

Comment: Unfortunatly i don't know which module will be included before running the task. All modules described in my config file. All modules stored in one folder in my project tree. May be i can include whole folder?

Comment: I found the way. But i can't unswer to my question because i haven't quiet reputation. Thats why i posted my solution into github GIST https://gist.github.com/syul/2dec564929d91b63d1f4